# Vue list item on click details

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this Vue app

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  data () {
      posts: [
          {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Post title 1',
            description: 'Post description 1'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Post title 2',
            description: 'Post description 2'
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Post title 3',
            description: 'Post description 3'
          }
      ],
  },
  methods: {
      getPostData: function (event) {

      }
  }
});
```

---

```
 <div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(post, index) in posts"><a @click="getPostData">${ post.title }</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here go description from clicked item

I want to click on an item in the list and display description from this item in #item-description div.

How I program this getPostData to grab description from an item on which I click.

Tnx

Comment: Would you please describe what exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: It will be useful to understand what is not working if you add the code you tried so far

Comment: For now everything is working. But how i program this getPostData to grab description from item on which I click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to somehow store the currently selected item or description. You could do this by calling a method from your template, passing by the item as a parameter. E.g. like this:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Post title 1',
                description: 'Post description 1'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Post title 2',
                description: 'Post description 2'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                title: 'Post title 3',
                description: 'Post description 3'
            }],
            currentDescription: null
        };
    },
    methods: {
        setDescription(item) {
            this.currentDescription = item.description;
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(post, index) in posts">
      <a @click="setDescription(post)">${ post.title }</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="item-description">{{ currentDescription }}</div>
```

---

If you want to asynchronously fetch new data on a click, you could fetch the data directly in the `setDescription` method.

---

**EDIT:**

It's probably also better to store the ID of the post than the description itself. In this case, you have access to the whole post instead of just the description. You can then also check if the current `<li>` is active and so on. Here is an example of this. In the example, I've used computed properties, which can then be accessed like regular properties. They are derived from the current state. So, `currentPost` always gives you the currently selected post if the active ID is set. The `currentDescription` then reads the description of the `currentPost`. You can access these properties the same way as regular properties of the state.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Post title 1',
                description: 'Post description 1'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Post title 2',
                description: 'Post description 2'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                title: 'Post title 3',
                description: 'Post description 3'
            }],
            currentId: null
        };
    },
    methods: {
        setCurrentId(id) {
            this.currentId = id;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        currentPost() {
           if (this.currentId !== null) {
               const currentPostInArray = this.posts.filter(post => {
                  return post.id === this.currentId;
               });
               if (currentPostInArray.length === 1) {
                   return currentPostInArray[0];
               }
           }
           return null;
        },
        currentDescription() {
            if (this.currentPost !== null) {
                return this.currentPost.description;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(post, index) in posts" :class="{ active: post.id === currentId }">
      <a @click="setCurrentId(post.id)">${ post.title }</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="item-description">{{ currentDescription }}</div>
```

---

Just as a side note: Storing the whole post as a copy in the data instead of just the ID is not recommended. By using a computed property, you don't have to worry about this property, it will always be up to date. For instance, if you change the `posts` array and remove the currently selected post from it, the `currentPost` will lead to a null value, without updating anything else. Or in the case of changing the description: The computed property always gives you the correct item (with the updated description).

Comment: I have one or question. Hove i added activ class to <li> item. Tnx

Comment: I've added a second example which is more proper. I'm storing the current post ID instead of the description. Then, you have always access to the full dynamic post. You can then also check if it's the active `<li>`. See above.

Comment: Tnx a lot. I'm new in Vue.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="main">
  <ul>
     <li v-for="(post, index) in posts"><a @click="getPostData(post.description)">${ post.title }</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

 methods: {
   getPostData: function (postDesc) {
     // you got the post Desc
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Vue 3**

*Script*

```
<script>
    export default {
       data() {
            return {
                posts: [{
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Post title 1',
                    description: 'Post description 1'
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Post title 2',
                    description: 'Post description 2'
                }, {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'Post title 3',
                    description: 'Post description 3'
                }],
                currentId: null
            };
        },
        methods: {
            setCurrentId(id) {
                this.currentId = id;
            }
        },
        computed: {
            currentPost() {
               if (this.currentId !== null) {
                   const currentPostInArray = this.posts.filter(post => {
                      return post.id === this.currentId;
                   });
                   if (currentPostInArray.length === 1) {
                       return currentPostInArray[0];
                   }
               }
               return null;
            },
            currentDescription() {
                if (this.currentPost !== null) {
                    return this.currentPost.description;
                }
                return null;
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

*Markup*

```
<template>
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(post, index) in posts" :class="{ active: post.id === currentId }">
      <a @click="setCurrentId(post.id)">${ post.title }</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="item-description">{{ currentDescription }}</div>
</template>
```